# After installing latest version of MySQL then I get error : #1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'group_id' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

After installing the latest version of MySQL I get the following error when inserting data into the database. My application was running old version of mysql but after update new version all application was breakdown.

mysql query like this :

INSERT INTO tablename SET group_id=''   etc..............

> Error :
>
> ## 1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'name' at row 1

also I have try to set --

```
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

but not resolved problems
So Please help!

Comment: Anybody help to resolve this problem because this issues help everyone.........

Comment: Please add your insert sql here.

Comment: INSERT INTO tablename SET group_id=''   etc ...............

Comment: Please add full sql in the question section.

Comment: Different error message in title and in body, missing query, not enough info. There is no 'name' column in the query like thing in body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Find STRICT_ALL_TABLES in sql mode and try removing it in my.ini configuration file.
```