# Can't get rid of Error Number: 1366 Incorrect integer value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

After moving a working CodeIgniter site to a new server it started to show `Error Number: 1366  Incorrect integer value: '' for column...` when updating or creating records.

Since there are around 40 fields to be updated and about two hundred functions linked to this I rather have a simple solution.  I added this code to the model in order to fixed any empty strings but somehow is not working either:

```
      foreach($data as $key => $val)
      {
        echo $key." => ".$val."<br/>";
        if ($val = '') {
            $data[$key] = NULL;
            echo "^^ string changed to NULL<br/>";
        }
        echo "<br/>";
      }
```

I have already tried the solutions shown on some answers to these questions:

[#1366 - Incorrect integer value:MYsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536199/1366-incorrect-integer-valuemysql)
[After installing latest version of MySQL then I get error : #1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'group_id' at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537139/after-installing-latest-version-of-mysql-then-i-get-error-1366-incorrect-in)
[After installing latest version of MySQL then I get error : #1366 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'group_id' at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537139/after-installing-latest-version-of-mysql-then-i-get-error-1366-incorrect-in)

Basically, removing `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` from **my.cnf** files, verifying that CI's database config parameter `'stricton'` is set to `FALSE` and/or setting `SET sql_mode = ""` on my php file.

I'm still getting the same error.  When running SHOW VARIABLES it shows that `sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`so I guess `~/.my.cnf` is not overriding previous configurations but I rather keep it local than global. Shouldn't CI's database config parameter override that `~/.my.cnf` line anyway?

Comment: `SET sql_mode = ""` is not the fix find actual error

Comment: is there any group_by code in your project add some of code on thatt

Comment: Thanks @AbdullaNilam - The actual error is a field that comes empty from the form but should be INT.  It worked previously assuming that an empty field means NULL.  It stoped working when upgraded the server but it should still accept empty fields as NULL.  There is no group_by on the UPDATE query I'm trying to perform.

Comment: @zJorge have you even checked if the column accepts NULL or if the value passed is NULL and not just an empty string ?

Comment: Yes @Andy - all these fields accept NULL and the value passed could be an empty string. I didn't mentioned but I added a foreach checking all (around 40) fields looking for empty strings and changing them to NULL just in case.

Comment: @zJorge, The error is probably caused because when you moved the project onto a newer server, your mysql version also changed from 4.* to 5.*, so if that is the case, you should dump your mysql since if you get those errors, it still means that you insert an empty string into an integer field, instead of null or an integer value.

Comment: Thank you @andy - What exactly do you mean by 'dump'?  I actually did a mysqldump when moving to the new server. I'll try UPDATE/SET to NULL everything set currently to '' but I don't think it will work since it also happens with records created after relocating to the new server.

Comment: @zJorge, with 'dump' i mean, print out the mysql query generated by CI with `$this->db->get_compiled_insert()` , so you can see the error in the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132344/discussion-between-zjorge-and-andy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you moved your project to a newer server, the mysql version probably also increased from version 4.* to 5.* which is less forgiving in terms of inserting empty strings into integer columns.

So you should update your code to change the empty strings into NULL or an integer value.

source: [MySQL 5 - Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1](http://www.garethalexander.co.uk/tech/mysql-5-incorrect-integer-value-column-id-row-1)